# Mpdf page break base on row and column

Tags: php, wordpress, mpdf

Suppose I have 10 data now I want to add these data in 1/2/3/4 row so on and within 1/2/3/4/ column so on
also page break. If I say 3 column 2 row then my 10 data will be divided in 2 page 6+4=10. Or if I say 2 row and 2 column then page will be 3. 4+4+2=10. How can I achieve this goal? Here is code I want to solve but it's not giving the desired output. I'm using [Mpdf][1] package.

```
<pre>
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $mpdf->SetColumns($column, 'J', 1);
    $n = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i< $column ; $i`enter code here`++) {
        $divided = ceil(count($orders) / $column);
        $content = '';
        for($j = 0; $j< $divided ; $j++) {
            $orders     = $this->orders->get_orders_info();
            if($n < count($orders)) {
                $orders     = $this->orders->get_orders_info();
                $rtl = $this->set_rtl($orders[$n]);
                $content .= "<div dir='$rtl'>";
                $content .= "<div style='$page_break font-size: $font_size'>";
                $this->order = ($orders[$n]['ID']) ? wc_get_order($orders[$n]['ID']) : null;
                // Actions Before Shipping Address.
                $content .= woo_invoice_before_shipping_address($this->order, $this->template_type);
                // Get Shipping Address.
                $content .= $this->helper->get_address($this->order, 'label', $this->template_type, 
                $column);
                // Get Order Metas.
                $content .= $this->helper->get_shipping_label_metas($orders[$n]['ID']);
                //Actions Before SHipping Address.
                $content .= woo_invoice_after_shipping_address($this->order, $this->template_type);
                $content .= "</div>";
                $content .= "</div>";
            }
            $n++;
        }
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
    }
    $mpdf->Output();
```